# SQL column not found issue

Tags: sql

When i run my code i get the issue column s.popchage2000 does not exist. please help

```
select name,
       SUM(population_2010 - population_2000) as popchage2000,
       SUM(population_1950 - population_1900) as popchange1900
from states as s
where s.popchage2000 > s.popchange1900
group by name;
```

Comment: That is as it should be. Use the aggregate column in a HAVING clause rather than a WHERE clause.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html says:

"Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined."

Comment: @LSerni: "Do not use HAVING for items that should be in the WHERE clause." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @BillKarwin I do not understand. That very page says, "The HAVING clause can refer to aggregate functions, which the WHERE clause cannot" -- and isn't that exactly what the OP is doing?

Comment: My mistake — the query is referencing aggregate functions, which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `GROUP BY` up in a derived table. And then you can use the column names in the main query.

```
select name, popchage2000, popchange1900
from
(
  select name,
         SUM(population_2010 - population_2000) as popchage2000,
         SUM(population_1950 - population_1900) as popchange1900
  from states
  group by name
) s 
where s.popchage2000 > s.popchange1900
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't  use alias column in  where (where clause is executed  before the select clause)

but for aggregated  columns you could use having clause instead of where

```
Select name, SUM(s.population_2010 - s.population_2000) as popchage2000
  , SUM(s.population_1950 - s.population_1900) as popchange1900
from states as s
group by name
HAVING  s.popchage2000 > s.popchange1900
```

having clause work on query result and can manage column alias

or for db product that don't allow alias in having clause you must repeat  the code

```
Select name, SUM(s.population_2010 - s.population_2000) as popchage2000
  , SUM(s.population_1950 - s.population_1900) as popchange1900
from states as s
group by name
HAVING  SUM(s.population_2010 - s.population_2000) >SUM(s.population_1950 - s.population_1900)
```

Comment: This is not a good practice. `HAVING` is for filtering groups.

Comment: I know  ..  but ..seems there is  group by  ..to me

Comment: Will only work with some dbms products, as it's not ANSI SQL.

Comment: I retract my comment and apologize for my confusion. It is fine to use HAVING to filter items by aggregate functions, or aliases on aggregate functions. My mistake, I was thinking of using HAVING for non-aggregated expressions just because you can reference aliases in HAVING clauses.